# htaccess to redirect a specific path on any subdomains to a specific path on the main domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have one .htaccess file (all subdomains point at the same file directory as the main domain, so one .htaccess file would need to accomplish this).  What I'm trying to do is this: any current and future subdomains should redirect like so:

```
sub1.example.com/cart
sub2.example.com/cart
sub3.example.com/cart
unknown_future_subdomain.example.com/cart
```

Those 4 subdomains and specific /cart path should all redirect to example.com/cart

I have tried different solutions but they caused redirect loops, I think because the sames .htaccess file is loaded on the main domain.

Comment: If `all subdomains point at the same file directory as the main domain` then `sub1.example.com/cart` will automatically load `example.com/cart` you don't need any rule for that.

Comment: *"I have tried different solutions but they caused redirect loops"* Add those rules to your post.